# why my .exe file works on another processor

Tags: c++, cross-platform

1. I compiled my program on c++ in release, and then I sent the exe of this program to my friend who has an AMD processor but I have Intel.  Why my .exe file works on his computer, although compiled programs works on concrete hardware and OS?
2. How to write code to satisfy the requirements of hardware independence?
3. where I can read about it?

Comment: AMD and Intel both use x86 or x86_64 architecture.

Comment: To be able to run programs compiled on Windows (or other OS) for Intel CPUs, AMD CPUs support the same machine command set.

Comment: In the case, of x64, actually Intel was the one who followed the approach of AMD. ;-) [**x86_64**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64)

Comment: I guess your 2. is about the executable not the code. Standard c++ is portable (in the sense that you can compile the same code for different architectures)

Comment: I confused, because I read that compiled module is tied to a specific processor (processor family) and will not work on others.

Comment: @idclev463035818 I mean compiled program, I sent exe but not source code which he can compile

Comment: yes I understood, just wanted to point out that your 2 refers to code when you actually mean the binary

Comment: @idclev463035818 ok, I'll fix my second question, I meant another idea, but I expressed in wrong way

Comment: The restriction is less about processor family but the command set and luckily that is standardized for desktop PCs (x86/_64). Therefore we don't have to necessarily dive into the mess that exists in the microcontroller field. That said, technically you can still optimize differently depending on the Desktop CPU. Both Intel and AMD offer own compilers that performs better on their CPUs under some circumstances (but it adds fallback code for the other's machines of course).

Comment: @AlexGeorg You've ansewered to my first question, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you compiled the code for a x86 or x86_64 instruction set processor.

So it both works on the Intel and AMD processors because they're both x86 or x86_64 instruction set processors.

Where it may start to not work is when you compile for another instruction set like ARM.

Comment: Would rather suggest to say "instruction set" and not architecture because architecture can refer to the internal design structure of the CPU.

Comment: Maybe, it's worth to mention that a c++ program is compiled for a specific platform. That includes code generation for a specific CPU instruction set but the OS plays a role as well. Leaving OS libs aside (which need not to be used necessarily), the binary format of executables may differ from OS to OS. Hence, (not far ago) a Linux executable for x86 didn't run on a Windows PC (before [WSL](https://www.notebookcheck.net/How-to-run-Linux-binaries-natively-in-Windows-10.282676.0.html) was invented) as the Windows simply couldn't load it.